# Tkinter: Resizing scrollbar without adjusting window size

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I currently have a scrollbar and a canvas on the same hierarchical level. In the canvas, there is a frame created using the canvas' create_window method.

I have a binding that is called when the canvas is configured that will resize the scrollregion to fit bbox("all"). It works, but **ONLY** when the entire window is resized (e.g. If I add more widgets to the canvas that are now not in its visible region, I have to resize the window to be able to change the canvas' scrollregion).

Ideally, the scrollregion should change as soon as the new widget is added to a nonvisible location of the canvas (e.g. it's off the screen). What am I currently doing incorrectly? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. It probably will take only take a couple dozen lines of code.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I am faciing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your mind correctly (you really need to include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with debugging questions!), you are recalculating the scrollregion only on receipt of a `<Configure>` event.  That only triggers when the widget changes size - and calling `.create_window()` on a Canvas certainly doesn't change its size.  The simplest solution would probably be to explicitly do the scrollregion recalc yourself, every time you add widgets to it (there's no event that is triggered by this action, as far as I know).  You might need to call `.update_idletasks()` first, to give the newly-added widget a chance to calculate its own size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a binding on the inner frame's `<Configure>` event to also reset the `scrollregion`.